# Point Cloud Library: Error while adding point cloud to PCL Visualizer viewer

Tags: point-cloud-library

I have a point cloud (.pcd) file, from which I have generated normals. Now I want to display the input point cloud along with the generated normals in the same viewer window (not in multiple viewports). The code I have developed is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/cloud_viewer.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <pcl/features/integral_image_normal.h>

int main ()
{
  // load point cloud
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

  if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> ("table_scene_mug_stereo_textured.pcd", *cloud) == -1) 
  {
    PCL_ERROR ("Couldn't read file table_scene_mug_stereo_textured.pcd \n");
    return (-1);
  }

  std::cout << "Loaded "
            << cloud->width * cloud->height
            << " data points from test_pcd.pcd with the following fields: "
            << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Input cloud Point Size "
            << cloud->points.size ()            
            << std::endl;

  // organized or unorganized normal estimation
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
  if (cloud->isOrganized ())
  {
    std::cout << "Computing normals Inside organized block " << std::endl;
    pcl::IntegralImageNormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne;
    ne.setInputCloud (cloud);
    ne.setNormalEstimationMethod (ne.AVERAGE_3D_GRADIENT);    
    ne.setNormalSmoothingSize (float (0.03));
    ne.setDepthDependentSmoothing (true);
    ne.compute (*cloud_normals);    
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Computing normals Inside non-organized block " << std::endl;
    pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne;
    ne.setInputCloud (cloud);
    pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ> ());
    ne.setSearchMethod (tree);    
    ne.setRadiusSearch (0.03);
    ne.compute (*cloud_normals);
  }

  std::cout << "cloud_normals Point Size "<< cloud_normals->points.size () << std::endl;

  //write the normals to a PCD file
  pcl::PCDWriter writer;
  writer.write("computed_normals.pcd", *cloud_normals, false);

    // visualize normals
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("PCL Viewer");
    viewer.setBackgroundColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);      
    viewer.addPointCloud< pcl::PointXYZRGB >( cloud, "cloud", 0);

    viewer.addPointCloudNormals<pcl::PointXYZ,pcl::Normal>(cloud, cloud_normals);    

    while (!viewer.wasStopped ())
    {
        viewer.spinOnce ();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to debug the code, I am getting an error

> **no instance of overloaded function "pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::addPointCloud" matches the
>   argument list**

in the line

> **viewer.addPointCloud< pcl::PointXYZRGB >( cloud, "cloud", 0);**

I have referred the documentation and spent quite some time in the web to solve this problem without success.

Am I adding point cloud to the viewer correctly? If not please let me know the correct way of adding the point cloud to the viewer along with the generated normals.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to add the wrong type of point cloud. Change the line to:

```
viewer.addPointCloud< pcl::PointXYZ >( cloud, "cloud", 0);
```

This question was also answered here:

http://www.pcl-users.org/Point-Cloud-Library-Error-while-adding-point-cloud-to-PCL-Visualizer-viewer-td4046232.html

For more information about types of point clouds, reference the PCL library here: 
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/adding_custom_ptype.php#what-pointt-types-are-available-in-pcl